# Retornando diferentes mensagens em função dos resultados de uma função

Tags: java, android

Estou com a seguinte dúvida:

Tenho uma função que pode me dar 4 valores distintos. Gostaria de criar uma mensagem (string) para cada valor da função, para que a mensagem fosse liberada com seu respectivo valor, por exemplo:

Se a função retorna B, eu tenho a mensagem B, se a função retorna o valor A, tenho a mensagem A...

código:

```
 Double N1 = N1(b, a, A, B, C, D);

 String resultado = (N1 == A && N1 < nM ? "Tipo A" : (N1 == B && N1 < nM ? "Tipo B": (N1 == C && N1 < nM ? "Tipo C" : (N1 == D && N1 < nM ? "Tipo D" : "Passa!"))));
```

O valor da função é N1, que poderá se A, B, C ou D. Além disso, a mensagem "Tipo X" só deve aparecer caso N1 seja menor a double nM. Se nM for menor que N1, devo retornar a mensagem "Passa!"

O problema é a mensagem que obtenho é sempre "Passa!", mesmo quando nM é maior que N1.

Como devo proceder?

Answer (score 1):

Tente fazer algo assim:

```
Map<Double, String> mensagens = new HashMap<>(4);
mensagens.put(A, "Tipo A");
mensagens.put(B, "Tipo B");
mensagens.put(C, "Tipo C");
mensagens.put(D, "Tipo D");

Double escolhido = N1(b, a, A, B, C, D);
String resultado = nM > escolhido ? "Passa" : mensagens.get(escolhido);
```

Entretanto, você não forneceu muitas informações acerca do contexto desse código. Acredito que com mais informações acerca do contexto do problema, uma outra solução melhor deva existir. Em especial, se você der mais informações acerca do que são, o que fazem e para que servem as variáveis `N1`, `nM`, `a`, `b`, `A`, `B`, `C` e `D`, os tipos A, B, C e D e o "Passa". Recomendo que leia acerca do [problema XY](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/499/132).

Além disso, certifique-se de que não há nenhum erro dentro do método `N1`.